# Querying data using the SQL If or Case statement

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm building a market database using c# with visual studio 2010.
There is so much details, so basically what I want to do is to execute query in query, using case or if statement.

[image]

Here is a quick explanation: There is 3 main tables in my database, for simplicity purposes I will use English words (in brackets) instead of the original names.

1. Artikal(Items): Item_ID - Item_Name - Item_Category - Price
2. Narudzbenica(Orders): Order_ID - Customer_ID - Order_Date
3. Stavka_narudzbenice(Order_items): ID - Order_ID - Item_ID - Quantity

As u can see in the picture, there is 2 dataGridView windows. The first is to display items and the second is the customer card.

When customer clicks the Kreiraj narudzbu(Create an order) button, a new order is created in table Orders.
After that he will pick the items, writing the id and the quantity he wants to add in the textboxes.
When the Dodaj(add) button is clicked a new order item is created in the table Order_Items. Putting the order_id as the last order_id created.

Coming to the point. I want to write a query, to check if the added item is already added once before.

If true, the order_item will just be updated by update query.
If false, a new order_item will be created by insert into query.

Here is this part of the code I wrote, but it's not working because of the wrong syntax of the case statement i guess:

```
string query = "SELECT i.Item_Name as 'Item Name', o.* from Items i, order_items o " +
              "where i.Item_ID=o.Item_ID and o.Item_ID = "+textBox1.Text + " and o.Order_ID=(SELECT 
               max(o.Order_ID) from Order_Itmes as o)" +
               "; update repository set quantity= quantity - " + textBox2.Text + " where Item_ID= " + 
               textBox1.Text;  
string testing = "SELECT Item_ID, Order_ID "+
                + "FROM order_items WHERE Item_ID LIKE "+
                "CASE WHEN "+textbox1.text+
                " THEN Update(Order_items) SET Quantity= Quantity + " + textbox2.text + 
                " Else INSERT INTO Order_Items(Order_ID,Item_ID,Quantity) select 
                max(Order_ID), "+ textBox1.Text + ", "+ textBox2.Text+ 
                " from  Orders END;";
**
DataTable tabela1 = new DataTable();

MySqlConnection konekcija = new MySqlConnection(konekcionistring);

konekcija.Open();

MySqlCommand test = new MySqlCommand(testing, konekcija);
                                    test.ExecuteNonQuery();

MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, konekcija);
                                    adapter.Fill(tabela1);
                                    dataGridView2.DataSource = tabela1;
                                    adapter.Dispose();
                                    konekcija.Close();
```

Comment: Hi @Hussein, my answer is not directly relevant, but have you considered using Entity Framework? Its very simple to use and makes big queries like this simple since you can then use Linq statemetns. Which means you can use C# code to do IF and Else statemets.

Comment: Hi @Cornelis, Thanks for your answer, no I didn't. Actually, this project is for me, just to learn SQL and linking it with C#. So, I don't want to use any external Framework. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Entity Framework is an internal Windows library. When you move into industry its the most recommended solution, simply because writing SQL queries tend to be hard to debug and have errors. However, lets assume you are going to use SQL. Are you connecting to a MySQL or SQL Server DB? Your code implies MySQL but just want to be certain.

Comment: @Cornelis  Ooh I see, I will try it as soon as possible, but for now, do you have any solution for this certain problem? 
And yes, I'm using MySQL(phpMyAdmin)